# Create a jQueryUI 1.8 Button menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, drop-down-menu, contextmenu

Now that jQueryUI 1.8 is out, I was browsing through the updates and came across the new [Button widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/), and in particular one of the demos with the [SplitButton with a dropdown](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton). This demo seems to suggest that the Button widget could be used to create a dropdown menu here.

As a matter of discussion, I was wondering what ways there are to go about creating a dropdown menu with this new Button widget.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth noting that I decided to use [Bootstrap button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: I stumbled on this post.  And I thank you for posting this link!  Wow!!!  Bootstrap rocks!

Comment: The link above is showing an older version of Bootstrap.  The updated URL is http://getbootstrap.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to drop a list below the button, in a manner similar to the demo provided here for autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.

Essentially, you would replace the code in the [button demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton) that displays the alert "could display a menu with a selected action" with code that does just that.  This code can fire off one of the many jQuery Menu plugins out there, [like this one.](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu)

```
<div class="demo">

    <div>
        <button id="rerun">Run last action</button>
        <button id="select">Select an action</button>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#rerun").button().click(function() {
        alert("Running the last action");
    })
    .next()
    .button({
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        }
    })
    .click(function() {
        // Code to display menu goes here. <<<<<<<<<<<<
    })
    .parent()
    .buttonset();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also tell it to create the menu using the built-in button events:

```
//...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#yourButtonsID").click(function(){  
       $("#yourDropDown").show();    
    });
});  
</script>  
</head>  

<body>  
<button id="leftButtonSection">Do Something</button>  
<button id="yourButtonsID">Open Menu</button>  
<div id="yourDropDown">  
    <ul>  
      <li>Option One</li>  
      <li>Option Two</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```